# Preview url not working outside wp-admin

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, urls, front-end, previews

So, I created a link in the frontend which allows the user to preview their post. However, when I click on it, it takes me to the published post instead of previewing the changes I made.

Here is what I wrote:

```php
<a href="<?php echo get_preview_post_link($post->ID) ?>" target="wp-preview-<?php echo $post->ID ?>" id="post-preview"> Preview </a>
```

If I go into wp-admin and preview the post, it works fine.

Comment: Do you have revisions turned on?

Comment: Yes, I do. It is on